# Python - have a pcolor plot; now want a surface

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am currently able to plot a pcolor style plot from some data.  The data consists of three coordinates per data point (X,Y,Z).

My data is structured in the following way:

```
X: 1D array
   shape = [500,0]

Y: 1D array
   shape = [700,0]

Z: 2D array
   shape = [500, 700]
```

So the rows of my Z array correspond to the X coordinate, and my columns correspond to the Y coordinate.

Then to plot the data on a pcolor plot, I simply did:

```
plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,Z.T)
```

The transpose is needed because of how pcolormesh expects to receive the input data.

Now I want to plot the same data as a surface using `plot_surface`.  I am having issues, however, in structuring my data the necessary way.  Can anyone offer any guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`plot_surface`](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html?highlight=plot_surface#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.Axes3D.plot_surface) expects all the inputs arrays to be 2D.

You can use numpy.meshgrid to generate the grid points

```
In [78]: X = np.arange(500)                 
In [79]: Y = np.arange(700)

In [83]: xx, yy = np.meshgrid(X, Y)

In [84]: xx.shape
Out[84]: (700, 500)

In [85]: yy.shape
Out[85]: (700, 500)
```

You can then call `plot_surface(xx, yy, Z.T)`

Comment: You can even get less lines by using mgrid: `yy, xx = np.mgrid[0:700, 0:500]`.

Comment: @tiago nice, I just knew `meshgrid` (already from old MATLAB-times)